# I am getting Error during connecting firebase with react native ios

Tags: firebase, react-native

At first i did npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app then cd ios and then pod install and get error like that..

[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
then i use my pod file  `use_modular_headers!` globally...then pod install done ,but when i ran the project from xcode it gives me the Error..."glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google"  please help i dont know xcode and can't solve the issue ...please help ...thanks advance

Comment: I am getting this same error too as well now.

Comment: any solutions ...to overcome the problem

Answer (score 1):

I just initialized a bare react native project yesterday and ran into this exact same problem when setting up Firebase. I can't remember the exact sequence of steps I took to fix it, but my current Podfile doesn't include use_modular_headers!. Instead, I used "use_frameworks!" globally in my  Podfile, and commented out the use_flipper!() at the bottom as recommended in the comments. If you get the same initial error about static libraries, try switching the environment you're running from. I.E. if you've been trying from terminal by "npx react-native run..." use Xcode to compile the build, and vice versa. Hopefully that works, it did for me!

Comment: will it solve my issues ...it will properly install the pod file of react-native-firebase/app and it sucessfully build my react project using both the npx react-native run-ios and from xcode

Comment: @React_Coder Yes, it will propertly install the pod file for firebase/app. It's a versioning issue, Xcode can find firebase/app module but can't use it because it doesn't support modular headers. Also, you don't need to rebuild the project from both the terminal AND Xcode, try from Xcode first and if it doesn't work try from terminal.

Comment: if it does not work from xcode then how can i build it

Comment: If you're using a Mac, you can open the Terminal application and type npx react-native run-ios at the root of your project folder. This will build your project using React Native instead of Xcode, which may work. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup for instructions on running your app on any OS with React Native.

Comment: yes i will run it using npx react-native run-ios  but when build is required for app store upload then it is required to run from xcoed ...if then build failed what will happen?

Comment: My initial answer was to fix your issue via Xcode by adjusting your build settings (disabling modular headers and enabling frameworks). Have you tried this already? The npx react-native run-ios was a backup solution I offered in the meantime in case you needed to run your app urgently. It seemed to me that if you're beginning to install firebase then you're not publishing to the app store in the near future, which is why I provided that alternative answer.

Comment: when i did it will give me **The 'Pods-MyApp' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)** error during pod install what to do ?

Comment: Good, I reached this error as well on my way to solving the issue. Disable flipper, it's just a debugging tool for network profiling and error reporting - not required for building through Xcode. You can refer to my first answer response for instructions on how to disbable Flipper through the Podfile, and make sure to run pod install in your ios folder afterwards.